# Image swap not working in second go

Tags: javascript, html

The image replace function works for one swap ,but it does not works for another swap.
i have used complete paths for images in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Can Change Images</h1>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="file://C:/Users/dell/Desktop/asd.png" width="100" height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p>

<script>
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("file://C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Capture.png")) {
        image.src = "file://C:/Users/dell/Desktop/asd.png";
    } else {
        image.src = "file://C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Capture.png";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `getAttribute()` returns exactly what was in the HTML. It may be a `relative` URL.

`.src` returns a fully qualified `absolute` URL, even if what was in the HTML was a `relative` URL.

`img.src` will return values like `file:///C:/Users/dell/Desktop/asd.png` hence condition fails.

Try this:

```js
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  if (image.getAttribute('src').match("file://C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Capture.png")) {
    image.src = "file://C:/Users/dell/Desktop/asd.png";
  } else {
    image.src = "file://C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Capture.png";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Can Change Images</h1>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="file://C:/Users/dell/Desktop/asd.png" width="100" height="180">

<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two different things one is u are using a html document where u are calling a file and another is image so instead of using any other javascript events u can use file:///path

```
<script>
function changeImage() {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
if (image.src.match("file:///C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Capture.png")) {
    image.src = "file:///C:/Users/dell/Desktop/asd.png";
} else {
    image.src = "file:///C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Capture.png";
}
}
</script>
```